# Vaadin dialog Server connection lost

Tags: vaadin

We need to get rid of vaadin's default behavior when the "Server connection lost" message is shown. Our need is that the application doesn't show any message and doesn't block the user's navigation (a filter will handle it). We tried to set the following properties to not show the message, but to get the expected behavior we have to make two clicks, per second the application performs the navigation which is correctly intercepted by the filter.

```
    ReconnectDialogConfiguration configuration = UI.getCurrent().getReconnectDialogConfiguration();
    configuration.setReconnectAttempts(0);
    configuration.setDialogModal(false);
    configuration.setDialogText(null);
    configuration.setDialogTextGaveUp(null);
```

We need to demend this problem to the java filter that will take care of redirecting the user.

Vaadin 14.4.9 + Spring boot 2.2.5.RELEASE

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for that. Your best bet is to use CSS to hide it.

```css
.v-reconnect-dialog {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but removing the dialog with css, the user to navigate must two click. I would need to be able to navigate on the first click. Any idea on this?

Comment: I don't believe that's something Vaadin supports. What is the use case? Maybe there's a simpler solution.

Comment: I need Vaadin don't to block user navigation in cases where it shows a dialog like "Server connection lost". Currently when vaadin displays the message, the user has to click on the message and only then is correctly redirected. The implemented java filter takes care of redirecting the user. Reading the vaadin documentation of ReconnectDialogConfiguration seems to be the expected behaviour.          
If the dialog is set to modal, it will prevent the usage of the application while the dialog is being shown. If not modal, the user can continue to use the application as normally and all........